# Un jaring a file recursively in java

Tags: java, io

I have a program that unjars a jar file but I need some thing that unjars files recursively. I am aware there are programs on the net that can help me with the same but I have not found any one of them working

```
try (JarArchiveInputStream jarArchiveInputStreamOuter = new JarArchiveInputStream(
    sftpChannel.get(lsEntry.getFilename(), new ProgressMonitor()))) {

    JarArchiveEntry jarEntry = jarArchiveInputStreamOuter.getNextJarEntry();

    System.out.println("What is the jarEntry " + jarEntry);

    while (jarEntry != null) {

        if (jarEntry.isDirectory()) {
            jarEntry = jarArchiveInputStreamOuter.getNextJarEntry();
            continue;
        }

        File currentFile = new File(destinationDirectory, jarEntry.getName());
        File parent = currentFile.getParentFile();
        if (!parent.exists()) {
            parent.mkdirs();
        }

        try (OutputStream outPutStream = new FileOutputStream(currentFile)) {
            Instant start = Instant.now();
            System.out.println("Start time is " + start);
            IOUtils.copy(jarArchiveInputStreamOuter, outPutStream);
            Instant end = Instant.now();
            System.out.println("End time is " + end);
            System.out.println(Duration.between(start, end));
            jarEntry = jarArchiveInputStreamOuter.getNextJarEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code unjars a file when done there are 2 jars inside it I need to unjar those files also help aprreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to do recursion in Java? If yes, then just refactor the code you posted so it uses recursion instead of a while loop. Else, learn recursion.

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with Java 7 or better you should check the new API for [Filesystems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.htm). It allow to work with jar/zips like if they where normal files/folders

```
Path jarPath = Paths.get([path of the jar]);
URI jarUri = URI.create("jar:" + jarPath.toUri());      
Filesystem jarSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jarUri, new HashMap<String,String>());
```

After that you can use the [FileSystem](http://FileSystem), [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) classes and methods to work inside the jar like if it where normal files/folders

Comment: Its a jar on the fly I am not sure if the above would work.